# Can the possessive “my” be dropped before father/mother?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, possessives, early-modern-english, possessive-pronouns

Imagine you are reading and/or watching some hoity-toity broad speak from the ye olde era. Would it be wrong for them to say:

> “Father would never allow for it!”

Or:

> “What plagues mother now?”

In context of the character speaking to an an uncle or a friend. I’ve seen variations of “mine own mother” or “mine mother” or whatever, but not sure if there’s an actual precedent for the aforementioned stylistic choice or if it’s some made up anachronistic fancy. Any explanation or help would be super appreciated, as this has been really plaguing me lol!

Comment: Nobody would say _mine mother_, because _mother_ begins with a consonant. What I _have_ seen in 19th and early 20th century novels is people (ordinary people, not 'hoity-toity') refer to _my mother_ even when addressing a sibling.

Comment: “Hoity toity Broad”?  “Ye olde era”? Are you trying to be funny? Please carefully read the [Tour] and do us the courtesy of framing questions in standard English in an adult manner.

Comment: @david Well, I haven’t broken any rules in the guideline. Thankfully, my jokes are based on the English language as it seems you understood them just fine. And I meant no offense intended for my gender or for a time long past; of which, it seems, you belong more to the latter than to the former. Yawn!

Answer (score 2):

This has always been possible in English, no matter whether it’s a longer and more formal version or a shorter and more affectionate version.

**Any** kinship term used for family members has always been usable on its own in the manner of a proper name without a determiner, and not just as a form of direct address or as a title, but also as a term of reference in the third person just as though it were that person’s name.  That means you can always use it in a sentence like:

- Will  ____  help?

Of *Mother* the OED writes in particular:

> *Mother* is frequently preceded by a possessive (as ‘my mother’) or used as a form of address (where, except occasionally in poetic language, *my* is commonly omitted); it is also used without possessive (e.g., in quot. 1930) in the manner of a proper name (this usage was, in the middle of the 19th cent., regarded as unfashionable or vulgar, and later as colloquial).
>
> As a form of address, *mother* now tends to be regarded as formal or archaic, while more colloquial equivalents, esp. *mum* n.2, *mam* n.1, and *mom* n., are preferred (see also *mummy* n.2, *ma* n.3, *mama* n.1, etc.).

With the understanding that you cannot count on regular capitalization especially in older works, here are some selected citations from the OED:

- 1547   King Edward VI in H. Ellis Orig. Lett. Eng. Hist. (1824) 1st Ser. II. 148   Derest Vncle,..we have at good length vnderstanded..the good success [etc.].
- 1567   W. Painter Palace of Pleasure II. xxv. f. 237v   Then she sayde vnto him: Father, doubt not at all that my heart shall faile in performance of your commaundement.
- 1589   Pappe with Hatchet (1844) 25   The babie comes in with Nunka, Neame, and Dad.
- 1603   tr. Batchelars Banquet v. sig. E1   Sister, god-morrow, what newes I pray?
- 1608   W. Shakespeare King Lear iv. 150   Giue me an egge Nuncle.
- a1616 W. Shakespeare As you like It (1623) iii. v. 77   Will you goe Sister? Shepheard ply her hard.
- a1616 W. Shakespeare Comedy of Errors (1623) ii. ii. 155   Fie brother, how the world is chang'd with you.
- a1616 W. Shakespeare Coriolanus (1623) iv. i. 16   Nay Mother.
- a1616 W. Shakespeare Coriolanus (1623) iv. i. 28   My Mother, you wot well My hazards still haue beene your solace.
- a1652 R. Brome Queenes Exchange iii, in Wks. (1873) III. 501   King. Pull the fool off me. Jeff. O but they shall not, neam, 'tis more than they can do.
- 1680   R. Thoresby Diary 10 July (1830) I. 49   Writing letters about some urgent business; at Holbeck with Aunt; and other visits took up the rest of the day.
- 1714   C. Johnson Country Lasses i. i   Cousin, thou art a very wild fop.
- 1773   F. Gentleman Pantheonites ii. 36   Why aunt says as how that I must not spit the butterfly on a pin.
- 1778   F. Burney Evelina II. xxiii. 222   Father grew quite uneasy, like, for fear of his Lordship's taking offence.
- 1781   S. Hoole Mod. Manners 40   When aunty cries, in spite, ‘Kitty, stay at home to night;’ And uncle's sorry I go out so.
- 1787   E. Inchbald tr. A.-J. Damaniaut Midnight Hour ii. 18   Do not be alarmed, uncle—force is seldom used, but to her that is willing.
- 1796   F. Burney Camilla III. v. viii. 131   Why, I never frightened him..like t'other poor nuncle.
- 1827   J. F. Cooper Prairie I. iii. 42   I wish it was hot noon now, grand'ther.
- 1835   C. Brontë Let. 12 Jan. (1992) I. 135   Papa, and Aunt both think a fortnight amply sufficient.
- 1850   Ld. Tennyson In Memoriam xxxi. 50   Where wert thou, brother, those four days?
- 1852   H. B. Stowe Uncle Tom's Cabin II. xxvi. 100   Won't you ask aunty to come and cut it for me?
- 1857   W. M. Thackeray in Harper's Mag. Dec. 95/2   Only this mornin', when you went out, my darter says, ‘Father, do you know why you have a black coat on?’
- 1867   W. James Let. 26 Sept. (1920) I. 105   I remember days passed in Grandma's old house in Albany.
- 1930   A. Ransome Swallows & Amazons vi. 71   Mother says I must give you plenty of lettuces and peas and things, or else you'll all get scurvy.
- 1932   G. Heyer Devil's Cub i. 15   Aunt Fanny has already warned Tante against your nobody.
- 1958   P. Roberts Cornflakes & Beaujolais iii. 17   Grandma got up at three, fixed us our breakfast, and saw us off at four.
- 1973   K. Brathwaite Arrivants: Rights of Passage 20   But to hell with this, nuncle! You fussy black Uncle Tom.
- 2003   M. Arnold Game with Dice (2004) vi. 254   I was sure that Aunt was not aware of the letter or the gift.
- 2012   R. Rash Cove ii. 25   ‘What do you need to buy, sister?’ Hank asked.

Comment: 'Any kinship term used for family members has always been usable on its own in the manner of a proper name without a determiner, and not just as a form of direct address or as a title, but also as a term of reference in the third person just as though it were that person’s name. That means you can always use it in a sentence like:

Will  ____  help?' ??? cousin? nephew? sibling? 'your cousin', 'his nephew'OK  ... I'm not sure about '... sibling'.

Answer (score 1):

It was still common in the past century and it can be found nowadays. The word "mother" is often capitalized in this context of omission. Here are some results from the Google research for "What is Mother doing now".

([A Secret Mind - 2012](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/A_Secret_Mind/TfOcDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&pg=PT218&printsec=frontcover)) They seemed almost normal to her now. But the few with their raving and sudden rages, when they would throw things — even bulky items of furniture — frightened her, and she kept out of their way. What was Mother doing now, she wondered? And Jack? If only theycould go back to when Father was still alive, before Arnold Price had come into their lives.

([Behave - 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Behave/7JamCQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&pg=PA290&printsec=frontcover)) “What's Mother doing now, Billy?” John asked. Billy shrugged, but he didn't look unhappy, just excited to see a toy that had disappeared from his little-boy universe for too many days.

([Mothertime: A Novel - 2013](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Mothertime/bUkh-W-JrBEC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&pg=PT63&printsec=frontcover)) What is Mother doing now? Is she awake, down there in the gym? Vanessa listens hard for any signs of disturbance from Mother because the basement steps lead into the drop directly to the left of the front door.

([Studies in Modern Jewish Social History - Volume 10 -  1973](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Studies_in_Modern_Jewish_Social_History/pp0WAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22mother+doing+now%22&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&printsec=frontcover))  Teacher : Little boy , little boy , what are father and mother doing now ? Child : My father and mother are having a grand celebration now . Teacher : Is it because you are beginning to study the Pentateuch that your father and mother ...

([Reading for Meaning: High roads  - 1949](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Reading_for_Meaning_High_roads_grade_4/FEANAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22mother+doing+now%22&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&printsec=frontcover)) What is Mother doing now, Mary ? ... Yes , she is helping Penny take off her sweater . Does Penny know where her ball is yet ? Sally ? ... No , she probably doesn't . She is not looking at it

([Teaching English to the Deaf - Numéro 3 -
1979](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Teaching_English_to_the_Deaf/OAbuAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22mother+doing+now%22&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&printsec=frontcover)) A. What is mother doing now ? B. Mother is feeling the material now . C. How does the material feel ? D. The material feels soft . Exercise 3 : Make correct sentences .

([Klaus Hinrich Baas: The Story of a Self-made Man - 1911](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Story_of_a_Self_Made_Man/1d9VQxXt4GsC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22mother+doing+now%22&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&printsec=frontcover)) What was mother doing now - she was probably still sitting at her machine , sewing , sewing , sewing , to get bread enough for her five children

([Cross Section: A Collection of New American Writing 1947](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cross_Section/SOpZAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22mother+doing+now%22&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&printsec=frontcover)) What is Mother doing now ? " Amory whispered back , holding to her older sister's corduroy overalls . " She is bending over Daddy , tucking in his napkin , ” said Louisa.

([The Literary Half-yearly - Volumes 5 à 7 -
1964](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Literary_Half_yearly/DDsZAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22mother+doing+now%22&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&printsec=frontcover)) -What is mother doing now ? Ambuja asked . -Cooking , she said . -Father ? Ambuja enquired . Radha indicated by an appropriate motion of her finger that he was shaving

([The New York Times Film Reviews - 1969](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_New_York_Times_Film_Reviews/AKVmAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22mother+doing+now%22&dq=%22mother+doing+now%22&printsec=frontcover)) . You know what mother's doing now ? " Leon asks Ursula after Pin has implemented their mother's death . “ She's vacuuming heaven

Comment: It might help to compare: *Uncle Vanya visited*. Not *My* Uncle Vanya visited.

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Totally legit, but you might want to lose the phrase "hoity-toity broad". There are more than a few daffy dames who would take offense, and there is no shortage of slap-happy skirts who would object, also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As both a daffy dame and hoity-toity broad myself, there was no offence intended and no offence taken on my end. But thanks for the heads up. :)